# Jackson weird timestamp value used in momentJS gives wrong year

Tags: java, oracle, date, momentjs

I use Oracle DB, column type is: `DATE`
I map this column like this:

```
private Date dateCreate;

@Column(name = "DATE_CREATE", nullable = false)
public Date getDateCreate() {
    return dateCreate;
}

public void setDateCreate(Date dateCreate) {
    this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
}
```

I am doing nothing else but just returning this value to the frontend.

In my frontend I try to convert this timestamp to a moment object:

```
let momentDate = moment.unix(dateCreate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

I get the `'12/13/49626'`
I should get `'08/28/2017'`

When I use a service like [this one](https://www.epochconverter.com/) and paste my timestamp(`1503908063000`) into it, it gives me the correct date.

I don't think, that cutting the last three numbers from the timestamp is a good idea. Is there another way to solve it?

I use Hibernate as ORM provider, and Jackson for JSON (some RESTEasy services).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use [`moment.unix`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/), that parses *seconds* since the Unix Epoch, simply use [`moment(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) that

> Similar to `new Date(Number)`, you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

Here a live sample:

```js
let dateCreate = 1503908063000;
let ggg = moment(dateCreate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
console.log(ggg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I again made it the complicated way. Thx for the answer.